# ubuntu12.04 hangs at checking battery state

Tags: ubuntu, boot, battery, gdm, intel-graphics

My 12.04 system hangs at "Checking battery state". At this stage, no commands work eg: ctrl+alt+f1, alt+f5. I ran recovery mode, I ran the command

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and gdm was the only one installed so I didn't get a GUI screen. I have an integrated graphics card "Intel Corporation Mobile 4 chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)". So I cannot install nvidia drivers as everyone else suggests. I have gone through several similar questions but everyone suggests reconfiguring gdm or reinstalling graphic drivers.

I did

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to get the latest x-swat drivers. The system still hung at the same line.

The other option is to reinstall ubuntu, which is out of the question, since we have a very specific install for our project where the settings are very hard to duplicate.

Suggestions/Comments welcome.

Comment: When I had this problem, the default display manager (lightdm?) was incompatible with my graphics card/drivers. Have you tried switching to another DM, rather than reconfiguring gdm?

Comment: So I have tried gdm and lightdm. What are the other options? I searched online, and I could see KDE/Kubuntu. Is that the other option?

Comment: `kdm` is the display manager provided by KDE, I'm not 100% sure if that is included in the normal Ubuntu DVD though. If lightdm was no different though, I suspect it may be a more general driver problem and I'm not sure what to suggest from here. S:

Comment: We found the answer but can only add a comment now as new user:

Comment: We installed lightdm and lightdm showed similar behavior, i.e. it halted at a certain step. However, then it was possible to press ctrl+alt+f1 and then login. The problem that there was a file called lightdm.override in the folder /etc/init. Inside the file was the word manual. This was how it was present on install of lightdm, and then running 'sudo dpkg reconfigure lightdm'. Upon removing this file, the system went to the login screen with no problems!

Comment: Glad you've got it fixed :) I think after a while it will let you put that as an answer, so you can then mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We installed lightdm and lightdm showed similar behavior, i.e. it halted at a certain step. However, then it was possible to press ctrl+alt+f1 and then login. The problem that there was a file called lightdm.override in the folder /etc/init. Inside the file was the word manual. This was how it was present on install of lightdm, and then running 'sudo dpkg reconfigure lightdm'. Upon removing this file, the system went to the login screen with no problems!